# Statement of the definition of decreasing/increasing function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, monotone-functions

I recently encounter a problem considering the definition for decreasing and increasing function. Here is what it looks like:

> Given a function $y =f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and a interval
> $(a,b)$, which is the right statement out of all below:
>
> **A.** $y=f(x)$ is decreasing on $(a,b)$ if and only if $\forall x \in (a,b), f'(x) \leq 0$.
>
> **B.** If $\forall x \in (a,b),f'(x) \leq 0$ then $y = f(x)$ is decreasing on $(a,b)$.
>
> **C.** $y=f(x)$ is decreasing on $(a,b)$ if and only if $\forall x \in (a,b). f'(x) < 0$.
>
> **D.** If $\forall x \in (a,b), f'(x) < 0 $ then $y = f(x)$ is decreasing on $(a,b)$.

---

The problem with this question, as far as I am concerned of my own, is that I do not quite understand how those statement are formed and relate to each other. It is even more complicated for me, since given the material definition:

> Suppose $f$ has derivative on $(a,b)$, then if $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(a,b) \Rightarrow f'(x) \leq 0, \forall x \in (a,b)$. Similarly, If $f'(x) < 0, \forall x \in (a,b) \Rightarrow$ $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(a,b)$.

It seems to me that I can not understand the logical meaning of those statements, thus I can't found out the difference between $f'(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) \geq 0$ in this case. Also considering that I have $f(x)$, what if the function look like this?

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

It is quite confusing for me to read the two definitions in a same line, and the way it is said also bugged me. Additionally, I kind of feel like I am misunderstanding at some point of the difference between **necessity** statement and **sufficient** statement, since the way the logical relation is connected in the definition is exactly $P \rightarrow Q$ as far as I concerned. But still to me it is quite difficult to wrap my head around it. What I have to do in this situation?

---

**Hint:**

> The solution to the problem is answer **D**, though the text provided no detailed solution or explanation of this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is not correct because some decreasing functions may not be differentiable. For example sequence $f(n) = -n, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

B is not correct because $f'(x) \leq 0$ means either $f'(x) < 0$ or $f'(x) = 0$ is true. Let $f(x) = 0$ be a constant function, then it definitely satisfies $f'(x) = 0$, so it also satisfies $f'(x) \leq 0$, but $f$ is not decreasing.

C is not correct and the reason is the same as that of A.

Thus D is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between the pairs A/C and B/D is just a matter of definition; when the relations involve strict inequalities, then we talk about *strictly increasing/decreasing* functions, while *increasing/decreasing* functions usually allow equality.

As for the simple or double implication, the double implication (i.e. the "if and only if" proposition) is not true, because a decreasing function, even when assumed continuous, is not necessarily differentiable. A simple counterexample would be given by $f(x) = -\sqrt[3]{x}$, which is strictly decreasing on all $\mathbb{R}$, but $f'(x) = -\frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}$ is not defined for $x \le 0 $.

In conclusion, as is, if I were you, I would choose the option B.

Comment: *I would choose the option B.* -- "B true" implies "D true", which is poor multiple choice construction, since without knowing any substantive content (i.e. by using only test taking strategy -- the hypothesis of D implies the hypothesis of B which by assumption implies the conclusion of B which equals the conclusion of D, and so we would have the hypothesis of D implying the conclusion of D, hence D would be true) we can eliminate B (assuming no more than one choice can be marked as true). In technical "testing trade talk", B can't be a key since if B were a key then we'd have multiple keys.

Comment: Why, you chose the same answer as me. But quite a reminder though, that the text itself does not fully convey things in exact senses, and even the question have no provided explanation. Anyway, thank you.